# write to file with echo/printf

Tags: bash, echo, printf

How to write the following to a file

```
printf "*\n!.gitignore\n" > $datadir/.gitignore
```

> -bash: !.gitignore\n: event not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

single quotes to avoid the ! being treated specially:

```
printf '*\n!.gitignore\n' > $datadir/.gitignore
```